# Как в content_types=['text'] выполнять несколько функций? pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

Возникла проблема: в декораторе  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) мне необходимо выполнить несколько функций, но программа выполняет только первую, а остальные просто игнорирует...

Вот код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from collections import deque
import time

wait = deque()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_messages(message):
    for i in range(19):
        if message.text == word_appearance[i]:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                             text=word_appearance[i] + "  ⟶  " + transcription_appearance[i] + "  ⟶  " + translation_appearance[i])


def get_in_message(message):
    into = message.text
    wait.append(into)
    print(wait)


def get_out_message():
    while len(wait) == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    out = wait.popleft()
    return out
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы каждая из этих функций выполняла свою работу? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если код выше верный, то на мой взгляд правильнее будет вынести функции get_in_message и get_out_message за пределы хэндлера (можно даже в модуль) и просто обращаться к ним при необходимости.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from collections import deque
import time

wait = deque()

def get_in_message(message):
    wait.append(message)
    print(wait)

def get_out_message():
    while len(wait) == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    out = wait.popleft()
    return out

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_messages(message):
    msg = message.text 
    for i in range(19):
        if message.text == word_appearance[i]:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                             text=word_appearance[i] + "  ⟶  " + transcription_appearance[i] + "  ⟶  " + translation_appearance[i])

get_in_message(msg)
get_out_message()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from collections import deque
import time

wait = deque()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_messages(message):
    for i in range(19):
        if message.text == word_appearance[i]:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                             text=word_appearance[i] + "  ⟶  " + transcription_appearance[i] + "  ⟶  " + translation_appearance[i])

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_in_message(message):
    into = message.text
    wait.append(into)
    print(wait)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_out_message():
    while len(wait) == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    out = wait.popleft()
    return out
```